# How to set Edittext in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a ImageButton that starts Google's SpeechToText dialog. 
Also I'm using a custom Layout for my Dialog.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dialog_edittext"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingRight="34dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dialog_imagebutton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sirioriginalstate_teaser"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialog_edittext"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I have the `Imagebutton` and a `Edittext` where I have to set the text.

```
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                final EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);

                final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imagebutton);
                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        promtSpeechInput();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setView(view);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
```

The `promptSpeechInput` method starts the Speech dialog.

```
    private void promtSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 6000);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            "Aufnahme...");

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_TO_TEXT_REQUEST);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test01", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If something is spoken the `onActivityResult` method will be called.
And there is my Problem.

How can I set the spoken words into the Dialogs `Edittext`?

I used the same previously but it does not help this time.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                textField.setText(textField.getText() + " " + result.get(0));
            }
            break;
```

I tried to do something on my own but this don't work:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

            final EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
            text.setText(text.getText().toString() + " " + result.get(0));
        }
```

Comment: You can use DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog so you can handle onActivityResult method right in the fragment

Comment: Or remember reference to the view when you show AlertDialog instead of inflating it again in the onActivityResult method

Comment: how can i reference to the view inside the AlertDialog?

Comment: Use field within activity when you creating your AlertDialog view `View mAlertDialogView;` ... `mAlertDialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);`

Comment: Maybe you have to know that the dialog is inside the `onOptionsItemSelected` method. So i don't think i can make a field inside my Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to forward the result of the called activity to the dialog. Since it is the calling activity that receives the result, the calling activity must pass the result to the dialog. Usually this is done via a listener. The calling activity will have a member of some type like

```
interface MyActivityListener {
    void onMyActivityResult(String s);
};
MyActivityListener currentListener;
```

and ideally your dialog would either implement this interface itself or have a member,

```
// inside the dialog class
MyActivityListener mListener = new MyActivityListener() {
    void onMyActivityResult(String s) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But you cannot add fields to the dialog because you use a Builder. But you can wrap the dialog in a class.

```
// in CallingActivity:
interface MyActivityListener {
    void onMyActivityResult(String s);
};
MyActivityListener currentListener;

void onActivityResult(...) {
        if (currentListener != null) {
              currentListener.onMyActivityResult(....);
        }
    }
}

class DialogWrapper { // contains members that the dialog cannot contain (because the builder always returns an AlertDialog)
    View rootView;
    MyActivityListener mListener = new MyActivityListener() {
       void onMyActivityResult(String s) {
           ((EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myeditor)).setText(s);
           ...
       }
    }

    void showDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = ...;
            ... li = ...;
            rootView = li.inflate(...);
            builder.setView(rootView);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(
               new ... { currentListener = null; }  // !!!!!
            );
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            currentListener = mListener;   // !!!!!
            alertDialog.show();
    }
}

// how to use:
void someMethod() {
    new DialogWrapper.showDialog();
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can decide that although all these listeners are awfully kosher, it all boils down to the activity having a pointer to the root view. So if your activity is really small, you can just declare a

```
// in CallingActivity
View pointerToCurrentDialogRootView;
```

and have it set to null in the dialog's OnDismissListener.

Is it a good solution? Well, OOP is distribution of responsibilities, and the activity should not be responsible for doing anything with the dialog's EditText. OTOH, it already happens that it is the activity who receives the result that the dialog has asked for. My advice is: put all activity-to-dialog stuff in an internal class. Maybe, extend the DialogWrapper (above) to do everything related to the dialog, even if you decide to remove the listener stuff.